# ag grid auto complete cell editor doesn't work on enterprise version

Tags: javascript, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to use AutoCompleteCellSelector in ag-grid enterprise version. This is how my column definition looks like -->

```
fieLd: MY NAME_FIELD; headerName: MY_NAME, width: 400.
colId: MY_FIELD,
cellEditor: AutocompleteSelectCellEditor,
cellEditorParams:{
    cellRenderer: "rowDropDownCellRenderer"
    required: true,
    selectData:[
        { value: 0, label: "this" }
        { value: 1, label: "is" },
        { value: 2, label: "sparta" }
        { value: 3, label: "yolo" },
            ]
    placeholder: "Desk"
},
valueFormatter: (params: any) => {
        if (params. value) {
        return params. value. label || params.value,value I| params. value;
        }
        return ""
},
editable: true
```

But when I start application it fails with below error -

```
Types of property 'cellEditor' are incompatible.
Type 'typeof AutocompleteselectcellEditor* is not assignable to type "string | (new () => ICellEditorcomp) | undefined*
Type 'typeof AutocompleteselectcellEditor' is not assignable to type "new () -> ICellEditorcomp'
Type 'Autocompleteselectcelleditor' is not assignable to type 'ICelleditorComp'
Types of property 'init' are incompatible.
Type
* (parameters: IAutacompleteselectCellEditorParameters«AutocompleteSelectcelleditor»)=›void'isnotassignabletotype'(params:
ICellEditorParams) =› void | AgPromiservoid»'
Types of parameters "parameters' and 'params' are incompatible.
Property 'selectData' is missing in type 'ICellEditorParams' but required in type
"AutocompleteSelectcellEditorParameters<AutocompleteselectCellEditors'.
```

So my assumption is AutocompleteSelectcelleditor is not compatible with ag grid enterprise? Or am I doing any mistake?

Comment: @Superman.Lopez Could you please take a look ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

cellEditor: 'agGridAutocompleteSelectEditor', and then please check:

[If you want to reference ag-grid components that way (with string name) according to ag-grid documentation you have to register it into your gridOptions first.](https://github.com/avallete/ag-grid-autocomplete-editor/issues/64)

Answer (score 0):

```
import {AutocompleteSelectCellEditor} from 'ag-grid-autocomplete-editor';
import {Grid} from 'ag-grid-community';

const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowDatas,
    suppressScrollOnNewData: false,
    components: {
      // Register component into agGrid
      agGridAutocompleteSelectEditor: AutocompleteSelectCellEditor,
    }
};

const columnDefs = [
    {
        headerName: MY_NAME,
        field: MY_NAME,
        cellEditorSelector: (params) => {
              return {
                component: "agGridAutocompleteSelectEditor",
                params: {
                  required: true,
                  selectData: selectData,
                  placeholder: 'Select an option',
                }
              };
        },
    },
];
```